# changing webpage wallpaper automatically with fading effect

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, wallpaper

I am creating a webpage for my project which requires that the background image should change every 10 seconds with nice transition (like fade effect). I managed to change wallpaper automatically but I am not able to configure it how can I do it. Below is the code that I've written. I am facing 2 problems as mentioned below.

1) Whenever the image changes every 10 seconds, I see **BLANK BACKGROUND (WHITE BACKGROUND, NO IMAGE)**

2) I am not able to configure how can I add smooth transition like fading effect whenever the background changes.

**index.html**

```
<html>

<head>
<title>Home | BM&A</title>
<link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="css/style.css">
<script src="js/jquery-1.9.1.min.js" type="text/javascript"></script>
<script tpye="text/javascript">
    $(document).ready(function() {
    var curImgId = 0;
    var numberOfImages = 3;
    window.setInterval(function() {
        $('body').css('background-image','url(images/bg' + curImgId + '.png)');
        curImgId = (curImgId + 1) % numberOfImages;
    }, 10 * 1000);
})();
</script>
</head>

<body>
<img src="images/home_logo.png" alt="Logo" class="centeredImage" />
</body>

</html>
```

**style.css**

```
body {
    background: #F4EEFE url(images/bgImage.png) center center fixed no-repeat;
    -moz-background-size: 100%;
    background-size: 100%;
}

.centeredImage {
position: absolute;
top: 50%;
left: 50%;
margin-top: -50px;
margin-left: -150px;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

don't reinvent the wheel, research on what has already been done and extend if necessary this is the Charles Darwinish theory of programming. your answer lies on this page www.slidesjs.com/